# XSS: Can't follow 302

Tags: java, database, oauth, xss

I am trying to build an app using Java.  The app will access a handler for a database, which dynamically runs a query and returns the result.  OAuth is being used.  The app is running from one port on my server, and the handler and database are on the other port.  Here is a picture of how I think this all works, based on my rudimentary understanding of OAuth:

[image: Visualization of my application]
Please let me know if my understanding of OAuth is insufficient.

At first, I was getting an OAuth error with an HTTP 500 code when I tried to run the app.  I figured that this was because the OAuth key that it was using was not in the list of approved OAuth keys on the server, so I went into my code and stepped through with debug until I was able to get the key and secret and add them to that list.  Afterwards, I no longer got the OAuth error, but now when I run the app I get a 302 header returned with the location set to:

`server:port2/.../oauth-authorize?oauth_callback=[handler URL]?request_token_secret=[gibberish]&oauth_token=[gibberish]`

The request_token_secret and oauth_token are different from the ones that I added to the list.

Unfortunately, it doesn't actually follow the 302 redirect.  I'm not sure why this is happening, but I'm quite confident that it has to do with my app running across two different ports, and therefore running into XSS issues.  I'm not sure why this is happening, and I'm not sure how to fix it, because I can't use CORS, and they have to be two different ports.

EDIT:  I tried doing the same thing, but using a different server entirely instead of the same server with two different ports.  I got the exact same error, except that the token and secret in the redirect location were different.  So it's definitely a cross-site-scripting thing.

1. Does my understanding of how OAuth works (as drawn in the diagram) seem correct?
2. What exactly is going on here?
3. What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: No matter which OAuth we're talking about, you should **never** send the token's secret in the URL. May I suggest to just read the RFC of the OAuth version you're using?

Comment: It's OAuth 1, and the URL given is what the server is trying to redirect me to.  Presumably after accessing either the resource owner or the list.  The 302 just comes back to my browser and fails to run, however.

Comment: And are you building your own OAuth server or using someone elses?

Comment: I'm using somebody else's, although I have access to it.

Comment: I really recommend reading some documentation about OAuth. The RFC isn't that long and while it's slightly technical it's a very good and interesting read. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849

Comment: OK, I'm reading it, but I don't think that solves my problem

Comment: Once you understand OAuth, it's pretty hard to make a mistake in the implementation :-)